# Can't require core.async in Clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen, core.async

I want to require core.async, but the compiler throws an error when requiring.

I've added `[org.clojure/core.async "0.4.500"]` to `project.clj`, and tried various versions, but the compiler still throws an error.

This is my `core.clj`:

```
  (:require [clojure.core.async
             :as a
             :refer [>! <! >!! <!! go chan buffer close! thread
                     alts! alts!! timeout]]))
```

And these are my `:dependencies` in my `project.clj`:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
               [org.clojure/core.async "0.4.500"]]
```

The compiler throws:

```
Error compiling clojure/core/async.clj at (9:1)

Call to clojure.core/refer-clojure did not conform to spec.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out I just needed to restart Emacs, it fixed the problem. Somehow.

Comment: EMACS loads the required libraries upon starting up Cider, if you were wondering.